# Better Database Design for a Hierarchical Structure?

Tags: python, django, data-structures, nlp

I've created a bilingual dictionary app<sup>1</sup>, and it's currently very simple, but we're going to be starting to develop the entries more fully and I'm trying to figure out the best database structure for it. Previous dictionary projects I've worked on have used xml (since dictionary entries are largely hierarchical), but I need to do it using a database.<sup>2</sup>

This is what a typical, medium-complexity entry would look like (simplified a bit):

---

**dar**
*/dār/*

- noun

  1. house, dwelling, abode
     *ar-rājl dkhul ad-dār*, "The man entered the house."
  2. home
     *rjaƷna lid-dār*, "We returned home."
- verb

  1. to turn
     *dūr li-yamīn*, "Turn right."
  2. to turn around/about

---

As you can see, one word can have multiple parts of speech, so "part of speech" can't simply be an attribute of Entry, it has to be related to the senses. Each pos can have multiple senses (numbered), and of course each sense could have multiple near-synonymous translations. Senses may also have example sentences (possibly more than one), but not always. Thinking of how the entry parts relate to each other, I came up with the following structure, using five tables:

```
Entry
-id
-headword
-pronunciation
-...

PartOfSpeech
-id
-entry (ForeignKey)
-pos

Sense
-id
-sense_number
-part_of_speech (ForeignKey)
-...

Translation
-id
-tr
-sense (ForeignKey)
-...

Example
-id
-ex
-ex_tr
-sense (ForeignKey)
-...
```

Or, in other words:

```
                                  _ Translation
Entry -- PartOfSpeech -- Sense --|
                                  - Example
```

This seems simple and makes sense to me, but I'm wondering if it will be too complicated in the execution. For instance, to display a selection of entries, I would need to write several nested `for` loops (`for e in entries → for p in pos → for s in senses → for tr in translations`) — and all with reverse lookups!

And I don't think I could even edit a whole entry in the Django admin (unless it lets you somehow do an Inline of an Inline of an Inline). I'm going to build an editor interface anyway, but it's nice to be able to check things on the admin site when you want to.

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like there must be something clever that I'm missing.

Thanks,
Karen

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're curious: [tunisiandictionary.org](http://tunisiandictionary.org). In its simple, current form it only has two tables (Entry, Sense), with the translations just comma-delineated in a single  field. Which is bad.
<sup>2</sup> For two reasons: 1) because it's a web app I've written with Python/Django, and 2) because I hate xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate saving dictionaries in sql databases as well. Someone wrote this awesome helper already:

[Django Dictionary Model](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2451/)

I use it in my project as well.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) data structure (or json/bson) along with [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com)?

In python, it is much more convenient than `xml`.

For example you can simply have a list of python dict objects to represent the entire dictionary. Each element can be a structured as follows:

```
[{
    "_id": "1",
    "word": "étudier",
    'definitions': {
        [(
            "v",
            "to study",
            "j'étudie français",
            "I study french"
        ), ...
        ]
    }
}, ...]
```

where definitions is a list of tuples (first element is part of speech, second element is the definition, third element is an example in the first language, forth element is the translation of that example).

You can then easily index it within [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson) database.

This is a very simple structure and you don't need to deal with a over-complicated database with foreign keys. Using mongodb, retrieving definitions for a word is as easy as

`record = db.collection.find({'word':'étudier')`.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work, because each part of the entry will have attributes of its own. (Perhaps I should have specified that the example entry I gave above is somewhat simplified.) For example, the senses will need to have numbers, and some of them may have required prepositions. Each translation word could also have attributes associated with it (i.e., "dated", "profanity"). And, of course, I'll need to easily search by part of speech, translation, etc. Overall, what I'm trying to do would be far too complex for this kind of structure.

Comment: If this is too limited, you should have a full database design. You can use sqlite which is easy and lightweight. An example design: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Database/SearchableDictionary.htm

Comment: Thanks for the example, but unfortunately yo no hablo java. :-)
I already have a database (I'm using Postgres), but I'm just wondering if this structure for it is logical/efficient.